# Top 2 employee's salary difference from each dept

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can I find the difference of highest paid salary in each department.

```
DeptID      EmpName   Salary
Engg        Sam       10000
Engg        Smith     15000
HR          Denis     20000
HR          Archie    15000
HR          Danny     30000
IT          David     25000
IT          Chrish    40000
IT          John      35000
```

**Result should be**

```
DeptID   Salary
Engg       5000
HR         10000
IT         5000
```

Comment: ,Which database are you using..?

Comment: @Mansoor  I'm using MySql

Comment: Show us what you've tried, and explain what would happen if the two highest salaries in a given department were identical

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a **sub query**:

```
SELECT
  DeptID,
  (MAX(Salary) - (SELECT
    MAX(Salary)
  FROM your_table
  WHERE DeptID = yt.DeptID
  AND Salary <
  MAX(yt.Salary))
  ) sal_diff
FROM your_table yt
GROUP BY DeptID
ORDER BY DeptID
```

Comment: Got the output but can we reduce the complexity, here we are getting in NNN can we get in N*N

Comment: Don't confuse a set based language like SQL for any imperative language, they don't have the same runtimes.  You reduce the complexity by adding indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Find the 2nd max salary per deptId from the below query

```
-- Assuming a temp table named as #salary

select deptid, max(salary) as MaxSal_2nd from #salary 
where salary not in (select max(salary) from #salary group by deptid)
group by deptid
```

Use that query with inner join to the main table and derive the difference with max sal per deptId as below. So, final query:

```
select s.deptid,max(salary)-Max(dt.MaxSal_2nd) from #salary s
inner join
(select deptid, max(salary) as MaxSal_2nd from #salary 
where salary not in (select max(salary) from #salary group by deptid)
group by deptid)dt  --Second Max Salary per deptId
on s.deptid=dt.deptid
group by s.deptid
```

Comment: Got the output but can we reduce the complexity, here we are getting in N*N*N can we get in N*N

Answer (score 0):

Use the window functoins to get the Salary rank within department, then pivot and look for top 2 salaries and find the difference.

```
select 
baseq.DeptID,
max(case when baseq.SalaryRank=1 then baseq.Salary else 0 end) - max        
(case     when baseq.SalaryRank=2 then baseq.Salary else 0 end)
from
(
    select DeptID, EmpName, Salary, Rank() over (parition by DeptID order by 
    Salary Desc) as SalaryRank
    from TestTable
) baseq
group by baseq.DeptID
```